# How to make a transparent background image using r.out.png?

Tags: grass-gis, png, transparency-opacity

Can the white background of the r.out.png of GRASS be changed to transparent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried '-t' flag?  Its there in 6.4.1.

Comment: I'm using grass 6.4.0. Is there a way to use transparency for 6.4.0? If I will upgrade to 6.4.1, I'm not sure if my current program will work on it. I don't want to risk the project that I am currently doing.

Comment: Since the command is a separate tool, I'm assuming you could simply get the r.out.png.exe (assuming you're on Windows) from 6.4.1 and copy it to the bin directory (make a copy of the old EXE just in case).  I'm not really sure if the GUI will show the -t option, but if not, then you can use it by entering the command manually.  Note - I have NOT tested this, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Ah. I understand your idea. Yes I'm using Windows. Where can I get the  r.out.png.exe for 6.4.1 without downloading the installer WinGRASS-6.4.1-1-Setup.exe?

Comment: I can't see it on their site, so I zipped up the one from my directory: http://www.mediafire.com/?hfh7cwxs557f4jx

Comment: I tried replacing the old r.out.png files in the bin, it does not work. The r.out.png script runs on GRASS but it does not generate any image file

Comment: Unfortunately that's as far as my GRASS knowledge goes.  Hopefully someone else can chime in with a suggestion to your problem.

Comment: I just installed the 6.4.1 version. My program works fine. Thanks :)