# Can two versions of GRASS be installed in a computer and still run independently?

Tags: grass-gis, installation

GRASS 6.4.0 is currently installed in my computer. The script that I am trying to run is present in 6.4.1. It is stated in my [previous post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13067/how-to-make-a-transparent-background-image-using-r-out-png). If I installed 6.4.1, will my 6.4.0 still run? I don't want to risk uninstalling 6.4.0 since my project is currently linked to it.

Comment: If you have a second computer (or virtual machine) at hand, try it there first. Even if the answer should be that it is possible, it's safer if you try it once.

Comment: what is the operating system?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7. I tried running it on my Windows XP virtual machine, but there was an error. It was installed but it did not run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to manually install it (in windows or Linux) in different folders. There will be no problem. Since both of the instalations are 6.4.x they can share the same grassdata.